# Materialize icon positioning

Tags: css, materialize

I have a side menu using Materialize CSS. It has three menu items in it, each with an icon. My problem is the icon sits too high - the base of the icon is in line with the base of the text. I want it to be so the icon is in the middle of the text vertically. Here is how my lis look:

`<li class="logout-btn"><a href="#"><i class="material-icons">power_settings_new</i> Logout</a></li>`

And here is what it looks like in the sidebar nav:

[image]

If anyone knows a fix that would be great!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with vertical align

```
 i.material-icons {
      vertical-align: middle;
 }
```

If this doesn't work, try to wrap into a span the text

```
<i class="material-icons">power_settings_new</i> <span>Logout</span>
```

And then in the CSS

```
 i.material-icons , i.material-icons + span {
      vertical-align: middle;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

change from:

```
<i class="material-icons">
```

to:

```
<i class="material-icons left">
```

more info can be found here: https://materializecss.com/buttons.html